# Using two audio queues in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

In my application I am using two audio queues for play and two audio queues for recording. At a time only one record queue and one play queue is active. What I do is, first of all I start first record and play queue, then on some event I pause the previous record and play queue and start the another set of play and record queue. But when I start another set of audio queue after pausing first one, I am not getting voice recorded or playback through these two new audio queues. So is it posiible what I am doing? My callback functions of all queues are working fine. But I am not getting any voice recorded or played back in case of another set of audio queues.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem aswell, I beleve it was fixed by stopping the first recording/playing before the second is started (so not pause, but a full stop).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Just let me try.

Comment: Its working even after pause. I tried it. It was some other problem. We can use the way I described in question.